# Turning random cube to random sphere in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

So my issue is that i am trying to create a random star chart within three.js that when zoomed out becomes a planet(sphere) created from the stars.

Currently the code im using randomly generates my stars yet when i zoom out it is a cube, not a sphere.

```
    for (var i = 0;i<2000;i++){
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
                mesh.position.x = ( Math.random() - 0.5) * 4000 * Math.random();
                mesh.position.y = ( Math.random() - 0.5) * 4000* Math.random() ;
                mesh.position.z = ( Math.random() - 0.5) * 4000* Math.random() ;

                mesh.rotation.x = Math.random();
                mesh.rotation.y = Math.random();
                mesh.rotation.z = Math.random();

                scene.add(mesh);
                objects.push(mesh);
            }
```

This is the for loop in which i spawn my stars and line 3-6 are what determines the way the stars spawn however all i have been able to do is multiply the positioning again by math random to create a slightly less defined cube instead of my desired sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting mesh's `x,y,z` position like you do, try it this way

```
var newPos = new THREE.Vector3(Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5 ).normalize().multiplyScalar( 4000 * Math.random() );
mesh.position.copy(newPos);
```

Thus you set a random vector, then you normalize it, making its length equal to 1, then multiply it with a random value. In simple words: you set direction and distance.

There's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/rhoje2wu/) example with both solutions (mine and Adder's)

Answer (score 1):

Just prune the stars outside a sphere:

```
var R=2000;
for (var i = 0;i<2000;){
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
    mesh.position.x = ( Math.random() - 0.5) * R*2 * Math.random();
    mesh.position.y = ( Math.random() - 0.5) * R*2 * Math.random() ;
    mesh.position.z = ( Math.random() - 0.5) * R*2 * Math.random() ;

    mesh.rotation.x = Math.random();
    mesh.rotation.y = Math.random();
    mesh.rotation.z = Math.random();

    var distance_squared = mesh.position.x*mesh.position.x + mesh.position.y*mesh.position.y + mesh.position.z*mesh.position.z;

    if(distance_squared <= R*R) {
        scene.add(mesh);
        objects.push(mesh);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems `if (mesh.position.length() <= R)` would work too

Comment: Yes didn't know about that - but the square root operation it uses is kind of slow.

Comment: I don't insist ) There's also could be `mesh.position.lengthSq() <= R*R`

Comment: @Adder  would it be possible to have other objects orbit the sphere created by this code? sorry for asking another question, also i dont want the solution for this i'd like to try to learn it myself however pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know enough about Three.js to answer that, but you could place them farther out in a shell by using something like distance_squared <= R2*R2 && distance_squared>=0.9*R2*0.9*R2

Comment: @KAIATTEWELL see jsfiddle in my answer